# I have time & date function ,but I want to automatically update it , should I use set Interval Method ? How?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

This date and time function is good ,but it does not automatically running, can you show me pls how can I fix it ? Time just show up after reloading page , time is not running

```
  const initApp = () => {
   let today = new Date()

   let month = today.getMonth() + 1
   let year = today.getFullYear()
   let date = today.getDate()
   let currentdate = `${month}/${date}/${year}`

   let h = addZero(today.getHours())
   let m = addZero(today.getMinutes())
   let s = addZero(today.getSeconds())

   let time = `${h}:${m}:${s}`

   let output = ` ${currentdate}  ${time}`

   const datenow = document.querySelector('.datenow')
   datenow.innerText = output

  }

  function addZero(num) {
    return num < 10 ? `0${num}`:num;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand right?

```js
         const initApp = () => {
   let today = new Date()

   let month = today.getMonth() + 1
   let year = today.getFullYear()
   let date = today.getDate()
   let currentdate = `${month}/${date}/${year}`

   let h = addZero(today.getHours())
   let m = addZero(today.getMinutes())
   let s = addZero(today.getSeconds())

   let time = `${h}:${m}:${s}`

   let output = ` ${currentdate}  ${time}`

   const datenow = document.querySelector('.datenow')
   datenow.innerText = output

  }

  function addZero(num) {
    return num < 10 ? `0${num}`:num;
  }
  setInterval(() => {
    initApp(); 
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="datenow"></div>
```

Comment: yes, it is working perfect right now ... thanks